# How to change button color inside anchor and menu-separator class in wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress

[image]

Hey guys I am new to wordpress and have this task of getting green button to blue. So I found this button but its in anchor tag in class menu-separator is there any way that I can type custom css to make color blue.

right now I have this

```
.menu-separator .button{background-color: blue !important;}
```

Wont work because a is missing.

Comment: "*Wont work because a is missing"* - what exactly do you mean by that? If you think you need to add an a, have you tried and what happened?

Comment: User `button` instead of `.button` :) _"." is used when you want to apply style on a class._

Comment: @FluffyKitten the button is inside anchor tag. So I thought I would also need to include anchor tag. I was thinking that the button is nested inside anchor tag.

Comment: @RohitVerma thank you, It worked. Trivial but I could not get it. Have to go back to html and css lol.

Comment: If you thought that, then why didn't you include the anchor tag? That was my question. It didn't make sense that you would tell us what you thought the issue was but didn't try it (or at least didn't include the results in your question).

Comment: Actually I tried it, I did  .menu-separator .a-button{background-color: blue !important;} but didnt work.

Comment: Hey, guys you have any clue how can I change the text in that button.

Answer (score 0):

First off you put

```
.button
```

You need

```
a button
```

Also you cloud use this

```
<buttton style="background-color: green;">blah blah</button>
```

Though obviously you'll want to use CSS but just to test to make sure the problem isn't coming from somewhere else try that as well if the whole `button`instead of `.button` doesn't work

Also we can't see all your code so this makes it a little harder to help because I don't know how nested the button is.

Comment: The example to gave me is inline css. I cannot do that in wordpress, since i did not create the project. I have access to additional css part. Where I can add some css.

Comment: Can you add a class to the button then make the class have the background color different

Comment: Sorry didn't realize that was what you meant

Comment: Its totally fine. Thanks for the help. I actually had to go to chrome dev tools to see what is going on. Then there I saw that its actually button. Then i changed the css but had .button. So it did not work.